# Skolem-Mahler-Lech Converse

Tags: number-theory, recurrence-relations, combinatorial-number-theory

Can any periodic set of integers be realized as the zero-set of a linear recurrence relation? It's stated on [the OEIS page for eventually periodic sequences](https://oeis.org/wiki/Eventually_periodic_sequences) that "all eventually periodic sequences with period N are linear recurrence relations of order at most N" but if you interpret "are linear recurrence relations" as being the zero set of a linear recurrence relation this statement can't be true because Skolem-Mahler-Lech gives a stronger characterization than just eventually periodic (the zero-set must include every earlier member of the residue classes in the periodic part too). At the moment I don't see an obvious way to do it for periodic sets and can't find any other mention online